# my function increment does not print 6 when called 3 times using a global variable

Tags: c++, increment

I have a header called "counter.h":

```
#ifndef REMAINDER_COUNTER_H
#define REMAINDER_COUNTER_H

extern int count;
int read();
int increment();
int decrement();


#endif //REMAINDER_COUNTER_H
```

the c++ file called counter.cpp:

```
int count;

int read(){
    return count;
}

int increment(){
    if (count < 5)
        count++;
    return count;
}

int decrement(){
    if (count > 0)
        count--;
    return count;
}
```

and the main file called "mainxc.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "counter.h"


int main(){
    count = 2;
    for (int i = count; i <= 6; i+=2)
        increment();
    std::cout << read();
}
```

I am trying to get 6 by only using the function read() 3 times but it does not print 6 but 5. Why is that?

Comment: you only increment if count < 5 , that means you only increment if it's 4 or lower. If count is 5 you no longer increment.

Comment: You also only call `increment` three times, so `count` will be incremented from `2` to `5`. No more attempts to increase `count` will be made.

Comment: Yeah but I want 6  , how do I get 6? it's supposed to get 6 when using increment and it is count <= 5 , I mean when count reaches up to 5 <= 5 , it gives 6 , isn't it?

Comment: Side note, unlearn to use global variables. In this case make a class with member count.

Comment: A class , I haven't thought of it because I only wanted a simple main function but not a class, is that possible?

Comment: You have the condition `if (count < 5)`, but it seems you want `if (count <= 5)`. Then you need to modify the loop so it calls `increment` at least once more. Perhaps you want `while (count < 6)` instead, as the loop?

Comment: Yes , that's right , I changed 6 in the increment function but why does not it work with 5 instead of 6? , is that possible to do that without modifying the value in the conditional?

Comment: Take a look at your current condition, `if (count < 5)`... Do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with that condition. What happens when `count` is `4`? What happens when `count` is `5`?

Comment: It's the first time I see that term but I am taking a look at it now

Comment: I achieved to get 6 as a result but I had to change : count < 5 for count <= 5 and for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) instead of for (int i = count; i <= 6; i+=2)) , it seems that if I had not changed that part of the code I would not have obtanied the result

Comment: Why do you have two places controlling the maximum count? what purpose does `if (count < 5)` have in `increment`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a class :

```
#include <iostream>

// You have an invariant in your code 0 <= m_count <= 5
// in C++ that means : wrap it in a class (one of the main
// responsibility of classes is to safeguard invariants)

class counter_t
{
public:
    int increment()
    {
        if (m_count < 5) 
        {
            ++m_count;
        }

        return m_count;
    }

    int decrement()
    {
        if (m_count > 0) 
        {
            --m_count;
        }

        return m_count;
    }

    int get() // kind of convention to call readouts get (or get_count);
    {
        return m_count;
    }

private:
    int m_count{ 0 }; // Initializes m_count to 0
};

int main()
{
    counter_t counter;
    for(int n=0; n < 7; ++n) // convention is to use `<` instead of `<=`
    {
        counter.increment();
    }

    std::cout << counter.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent ! thanks very much for that @Pepijn Kramer, I am going to run it now

Comment: I added 6 in the increment function like: int increment(){
    if (count < 6)
        count++;
    return count;
} and finally worked but I was only curious , why did not it print 6 with 5 in the increment function?

Comment: @JosueOliva Once again: Explain to your rubber duck what happens when `m_count` is 5 and `increment()` is called.

Comment: Have you debugged your code yet? E.g. run in debugger and single step through each line, observe what variables are doing an where your functions return. (I added scopes so you have one statement per line which makes debugging line by line more easy)